# How do I change my display settings if I can't see my screen?

Tags: snow-leopard, display

I have a macbook in clamshell mode that's plugged into an HDTV for display output.  Yesterday, I changed my display settings via the System Preferences.  However, I inadvertently picked a setting that is not supported by my screen, and now I can't figure out how to undo the change.  The screen is blank.

I can open my laptop and go to dual-screen mode and change the settings there, but as soon as I switch back to clamshell mode the system picks the broken display settings again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to to go `/Library/Preferences/` and search for `com.apple.windowserver.plist`. It's the file that gets updated when you modify the display in `System Preferences` (I just tried).

According to [**this Apple KB**](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS2084), it's safe to delete it. So move it on your desktop and try to reboot.

Comment: Interesting point, to get the system to re-generate on re-boot.  I found 'some' display setting values on in a com.apple.preference.displays2.XXXXXXXX plist file in ~/Library/Preferences/ByHost. NB: I do have 2 monitors, hence the "display2"?

Comment: @petert Now that I checked on my Mac, I updated the post with the correct information.

Answer (score 1):

From the command line, [cscreen](http://hintsforums.macworld.com/showthread.php?p=315509) lets you adjust monitor resolution.